# Images generated from SummerNote WYSIWYG Bootstrap broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, summernote

I am using Summer Note (http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) in my CMS to edit pages. For images, summer note allows you to insert images as img tag with a bunch of data (not uploaded to the server and stored in filesystem, but stored directly into database). So I am storing images within the HTML text, which is all stored in my postgres database (data type is text).

When the html is displayed on the front end, the text shows up fine but the images are broken. Is this due to the data type (text) or does there exist a better WYSIWYG bootstrap solution that allows uploading of images, as well as resizing them? Or perhaps a hack that could get around that to using uploaded images to the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding .html_safe

Example:

@page.content.html_safe